# ¿Cómo se obtiene el valor de un campo seleccionado en Html.Dropdownlist de MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc

Estoy haciendo un login en MVC 5 que tiene los campos de "Sucursal", "Usuario" y "Contraseña", donde Sucursal es un dropdownlist que se llena con la información de una base de datos. Quiero saber como puedo tomar el valor seleccionado del dropdownlist y utilizarlo.

Mi modelo es este:

```
public class ListarSucursal
{
    public int IdSucursal { get; set; }
    public string NombreSucursal { get; set; }
    public SelectList DatosSucursal { get; set; }

}

public class Listar
{
    public IEnumerable<ListarSucursal> GetSucursales()
    {

        string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var sucursales = new List<ListarSucursal>();
        var conObj = new SqlConnection(connection);
        conObj.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand("Select IdSucursal, NombreSucursal from Sucursal ORDER BY NombreSucursal", conObj);

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            sucursales.Add(new ListarSucursal { NombreSucursal = Convert.ToString(reader["NombreSucursal"]), IdSucursal = Convert.ToInt32(reader["IdSucursal"]) });

        }

        return sucursales;

    }


}
```

El controlador:

```
 public ActionResult Login()
    {

        ListarSucursal LS = new ListarSucursal();
        LS.DatosSucursal = new SelectList(listar.GetSucursales(),   "IdSucursal", "NombreSucursal");
        return View(LS);
    }
```

Y la vista:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("DatosSucursal", null, new {
                   style = "width: 300px; height: 35px; border-radius: 5px; border-color: #C4C1C1 " })
```

He intentado con los ejemplos que he encontrado en internet pero ninguno ha conseguido que el valor se guarde, así que les agradecería mucho su ayuda :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias definir en el modelo la propiedad `IdSucursal` donde recibiras el valor en el `POST`

```
public class ListarSucursal
{
   public int IdSucursal { get; set; }
   public string NombreSucursal { get; set; }
   public int IdSucursal { get; set; }

   public SelectList DatosSucursal { get; set; }
}
```

En la view usarias un `@Html.DropDownListFor()`, entonces cuando realizas el post enviara el name para que lo aplique en el model binding

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Login", Method.Post, ...)){

   @Html.DropDownListFor(x=> x.IdSucursal, Model.DatosSucursal, null, new {...})
}
```

Con esto en el controller podrias usar

```
public class LoginController : Controller{

   public ActionResult Login(ListarSucursal model){
       ListarSucursal LS = new ListarSucursal();
       LS.DatosSucursal = new SelectList(listar.GetSucursales(), "IdSucursal", "NombreSucursal");
       return View(LS);
   }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Login(ListarSucursal model){

     int sucursalId = model.SucursalId;

     retunr View();
  }
}
```

En el action marcado con `[HttpPost]` recibes el id que mapea con el name del dropdownlist.