# ¿Se puede llenar un <select> de HTML con información de una base de datos usando JQuery y Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

tengo un proyecto asp.net donde hice un login con html y bootstrap. El login tiene los campos de Sucursal, Usuario y Contraseña, y Sucursal es un  que debería llenarse con una base de datos ¿Es esto posible con JQuery y Ajax?

Comment: Sí, es posible. ¿Has intentado algo o solo tienes la curiosidad de si se podía realizar o no?

Comment: Esta consulta no se relaciona con esta otra http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4756/c%C3%B3mo-se-obtiene-el-valor-de-un-campo-seleccionado-en-html-dropdownlist-de-mvc   porque se plantea un login con los mismos campos solo que aqui mencionas el uso de ajax y jquery

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no lo creo porque la pregunta que vinculas utiliza componentes propios de asp.net mvc 5 mientras que el OP no ha mencionado con qué tecnologías trabaja.

Comment: @Blue Estas usando asp.net o asp.net mvc ?

Comment: asp.net, el de la otra pregunta no soy yo pero si tenemos los mismos campos al parecer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si es posible, lo que podes hacer es armar el select y darle un identificador para llamarlo con jquery y luego podes con ajax buscar la información a un script del lenguaje que utilices para consumir la información de la db y mostrarlo dentro del select..

Una opción simple que puedes utilizar es la siguiente:

**html:**

```
<select id="test" name="X"></select>
```

Luego con un ajax llamas a un script con el cual consultas a la base de datos y retornas el contenido del select ya armado.
Ejemplo de lo que te devolvería el script:

```
<option value="XXXX"> XXXXX </option>
<option value="XXXX"> XXXXX </option>
<option value="XXXX"> XXXXX </option>
```

luego en el succces del ajax que ejecutaste deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  success:function(data){
    $('#test').html(data);
  },
  error:function(){
    alert('algo fallo');
  }
});
```

Con esto ya cargarias tu select.